# will build number increase?

Tags: ant, jenkins, nexus, build.xml

i am trying to automate the build for my java based project. we are currently using svn, jenkins (builds), nexus sonotype(artifact rep.) and websphere(web server). this is my first project and i have to give a POC. the management wants me to kick off a build using jenkins which will save the succesful build artifact to nexus with a certain build number then we are trying to use the same artifact to deploy to QA ad promote the same build to other successive environments(uta, prod) from nexus. what would the ant script to be used and will the build number increase if i copy the same build artifact to different environment using the ant build script? thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's up to the client side tooling to set the version number being deployed.

For Ant, take a look at the Aether Ant Tasks:  https://github.com/eclipse/aether-ant

Configure these to do a snapshot deploy to Nexus.  This will cause new timestamped versions to be deployed with every run of the CI job.